# show database data into JTable

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

```
public class d7Table extends JFrame {

    String dbName = "mydb";
    String bdUser = "root";
    String dbPassword = "2323";
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb";
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stm = null;
    ResultSet res = null;
    public JTable table;

    public d7Table() {
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, bdUser, dbPassword);
            System.out.println("Connected to database successfully!");
            res = stm.executeQuery("select * from mytable");

            table = new JTable(myTableModel(res));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect to database");
        }

        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800, 600);
        this.setLocation(300, 60);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static DefaultTableModel myTableModel(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        ResultSetMetaData metadata = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
        int columnsCount = metadata.getColumnCount();
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < columnsCount; i++) {
            columnNames.add(metadata.getColumnName(i));
        }
        Vector<Object> data = new Vector<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector<Object> eachLine = new Vector<>();
            for (int i = 1; i < columnsCount; i++) {
                eachLine.add(rs.getObject(i));
            }
            data.add(eachLine);
        }
        return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new d7Table();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My Error:

```
Connected to database successfully!
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at JDBCtest.d7Table.<init>(d7Table.java:33)  // refer to res =stm.execute... Row
at JDBCtest.d7Table$1.run(d7Table.java:73)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
...
```

Comment: Just a side question: which IDE did you use?

Comment: @reporter I use NetBeans

Comment: I'm not familiar with Netbeans, though I think there must be also a way for debugging (I don't want to hurt you).

Comment: I know that was solved. ;-) I ask because it was a common mistake and with debugging you could figure out your mistake by your self. As I said I didn't want to hurt you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line

```
res = stm.executeQuery("select * from mytable");
```

The `stm` variable is still `null`, causing your `NullPointerException`.  You never initialized it.

The proper procedure to create a `PreparedStatement` is to call `prepareStatement` on the `Connection` object.

But you have no bind variables; you only need a `Statement` here.  Declare `stm` as a `Statement`, and after connecting, do this:

```
stm = con.createStatement();
```

Then you can execute a query with the `Statement` as you have already this line:

```
res = stm.executeQuery("select * from mytable");
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to obtain a `Statement` in the variable `stm` before querying it. Use this code to do so:

```
stm = con.createStatement();
```